# How to show the message from AsyncValidatorFn

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I'm implementing an AsyncValidatorFn.

Service:

```
public verifyExistingRegisterScheduled(workschedule: WorkSchedule): Observable<Result<any>> {
return this.dataService.post<Result<any>>('/workschedule/existing-register-scheduled', workschedule);
```

}

Component:

```
createForm() {
this.scheduleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  searchText: [this.searchText],
  codEnd: [this.workschedule.codEnd, Validators.required],
  dataInicio: [this.workschedule.dataInicio, Validators.required],
  dataFim: [this.workschedule.dataFim, Validators.required],
  periodo: [this.workschedule.periodo, Validators.required],
  justificativa: [this.workschedule.justificativa, Validators.required],
  totalColaboradores: [this.workschedule.totalColaboradores],
  totalTerceiros: [this.workschedule.totalTerceiros]
},
  {
    validator: [dateLessThanValidator, existingRegisterScheduledValidator(this.workScheduleService, this.workschedule)]
  });
```

}

Validator:

```
export function existingRegisterScheduledValidator(workScheduleService: WorkscheduleService, workschedule: WorkSchedule): AsyncValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return workScheduleService.verifyExistingRegisterScheduled(workschedule).pipe(map(result => {
        debugger;
        return (result.content && result.content.length > 0) ? { 'registerExists': true } : null;
    }));
}
```

};

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="scheduleForm.errors && scheduleForm.errors['registerExists']" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12">Message.</div>
```

The idea is, if as been returned values, than the error might be true.

Is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misconfigured an `asyncValidator`. See [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group) for usage

```
createForm() {
this.scheduleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  searchText: [this.searchText],
  codEnd: [this.workschedule.codEnd, Validators.required],
  dataInicio: [this.workschedule.dataInicio, Validators.required],
  dataFim: [this.workschedule.dataFim, Validators.required],
  periodo: [this.workschedule.periodo, Validators.required],
  justificativa: [this.workschedule.justificativa, Validators.required],
  totalColaboradores: [this.workschedule.totalColaboradores],
  totalTerceiros: [this.workschedule.totalTerceiros]
},
  {
    validators: [dateLessThanValidator], 
    asyncValidators :[existingRegisterScheduledValidator(this.workScheduleService, this.workschedule)]
  });
```